# NPOI makes a mess of xlsx files

Tags: c#, xlsx, npoi

I have the following code to write to an existing XLSX file

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(bestand, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
string ext = Path.GetExtension(bestand).ToLower();

if (ext == ".xls")
{
    wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
}
else if (ext == ".xlsx")
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

ISheet ws = wb.GetSheet(Maanden[maand-1]);

ws.GetRow(colum).GetCell(rij++).SetCellValue(huidigedatum);
ws.GetRow(colum).GetCell(rij++).SetCellValue(Datarow["Factuurnummer"].ToString());
ws.GetRow(colum).GetCell(rij++).SetCellValue(Datarow["Omschrijving"].ToString());
ws.GetRow(colum++).GetCell(tbBank-1).SetCellValue((double)totaal);

WriteToFile(bestand);
```

```
private void WriteToFile(string bestand)
{
    //Write the stream data of workbook to the root directory
    FileStream file = new FileStream(bestand, FileMode.Create);
    wb.Write(file);
    pBar.PerformStep();
    file.Close();
}
```

With an XLS file it works great.

Please help.

Regards, Rinaldo

Comment: What happens with xlsx files? Could you please include more details (i.e. error messages etc)?

Comment: Hi Simon, the xlsx file is corrupt. Can't load it anymore withtout an dialogbox to import and so in libre office while the untouched XLSX can be loaded in libre office. No error message while writing. Everything goes without problems, exept when i try to load it in libre office. Hope someone knows the answer. Regards Rinaldo

Comment: Please try NPOI 2.1. There are some critical bugs which will corrupt the Excel file in NPOI 2.0.x

Comment: @WordyFox I do still experience corrupted XLSX files with the version 2.1.3.1 of NPOI: When I manually unzip and re-zip the file, MS Excel 2013 is happy.

Answer (score 1):

What I think is error is in line

```
ISheet ws = wb.GetSheet(Maanden[maand-1]);
```

you'll have to typecaste the worksheet object with correct excel file type

try

```
ISheet ws;
   if (ext == ".xls")
   {
    wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    ws = (HSSFSheet)wb.GetSheet(Maanden[maand-1]);
   }
   else if (ext == ".xlsx")
   { 
      wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
      ws = (XSSFSheet)wb.GetSheet(Maanden[maand-1]);
   }
```